# Change the color of top navigation bar in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and I am working on developing a login application. The functionalities work completely fine. I want to change the color of the Navigation header(as shown in picture) from white to some other color. I looked but couldn't find a way to do the same. Can anyone guide me to correct pointer to achieve the same.

[image]

Here is the stackNavigation code that I am using :

```
const Login = createStackNavigator();
const LoginStack = () => {
  return (
    <Login.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Welcome"
      headerMode="float"
      screenOptions={() => ({
        headerTintColor: AppStyles.colorSet.mainBackgroundColor,
        headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
        headerRight: () => <View />,  
        cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#275362', }
      })}
    >
      <Login.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Login.Screen
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
        name="Welcome"
        component={WelcomeScreen}
      />
    </Login.Navigator>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red',
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the header's background color for all the screens in your navigator:

```js
<Login.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Welcome"
  headerMode="float"
  screenOptions={{
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    }
  }}
>
```

If you only want to change the header's background color of your login screen:

```js
<Login.Screen 
  name="Login"
  component={LoginScreen}
  options={{
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
  }}
/>
```